# Alternative Reduction Formula for $\int\cos^n{x}\,dx$

Tags: indefinite-integrals, alternative-proof, trigonometric-integrals, reduction-formula

I'm having some trouble showing this proof for the reduction formula for $\int \cos^{n}{x}\,dx$. I already know how to prove the regular reduction formula for $\int \cos^{n}{x}\,dx$:

$$\int \cos^n{x}\,dx=\frac{{1}}n(\sin{x})(\cos^{n-1}{x})+\frac{{n-1}}n\int \cos^{n-2}\,{x}\,dx$$

What I'm trying to prove is (what seems to be) an alternate reduction formula provided by my professor:

$$\int \cos^n{x}\,dx=\frac{{1}}n(\sin{x})(\cos^{n-1}{x})+\;\pmb{\left[\frac{{n}}{n-2}\right]}\;\int \cos^{n-2}\,{x}\,dx$$

Does anyone know if this second proof for the reduction formula for $\int \cos^{n}{x}\,dx$ is actually true, and if it is, can you show how to prove it...? If it's not, then I can let my professor know that that this proof is erroneous...

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should be aware of the fact that $f^{(n)}$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ derivative of $f$. The $n^{\text{th}}$ power of $f$ is denoted by $f^n$.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! I suppose that, in each of these equations, the l.h.s. should be $\int\cos ^n x\,dx$?

Comment: @Bernard: Correct... sorry. First time posting a question, so I'm still getting used to the way to write the equations properly...

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Apologies... That's a fair point. I'll make the edit...

Comment: Well I see no reason why $\int \cos^2$ would be infinite, so $\frac n{n-2}$ is certainly erroneous...

Comment: That's a fair point... I should bring that up...

In fact the next part in the question asks for the result for $\int \cos^{2}{x}\,dx$...